# Get changes on a local branch that has no corresponding remote branch

Tags: git

Let's say I create a local branch and then I commit to it 3 times. Each commit is a modification to a unique file.

How can I do a diff to see my changes to all of these files?

#### Conditions

- I have not pushed the branch so there is no remote branch
- The number of commits is unknown. 3 is just an example.
- I do not want to see changes that are not in commit. To be more specific, I do not want to see changes to files that are still in the index/staging area etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff HEAD~3..HEAD~2
git diff HEAD~2..HEAD~1
git diff HEAD~1`

Or changes against HEAD:

`git diff HEAD~2
git diff HEAD~3`

Or show can show you changes per revision in a patch format:

`git show HEAD~2
git show HEAD~1
git show`

Comment: Please see my edit about the conditions. I provided more conditions

Answer (score 0):

Edmundo's answer solves all your question.

If you want to see n'th commit try `git diff HEAD~n..HEAD~(n+1)`. e.g. if n = 4, `git diff HEAD~4..HEAD~3`. This will show you only the changes made in the 4th commit.

If you need to see more details, then `git show HEAD~n` works (where you want to see the nth commit's details).

Documentation for both are really good and should help

- [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)
- [git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

Comment: I think I need to clarify even further - I don't know the number of commits. And just I have read the documentation and am still struggling to the find the particular command.

Comment: - git help diff

Comment: You can try using [git log](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to see what commits you have made. They should help you understand how far you need to go back.  

Perhaps [this tutorial about viewing commit history](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) might be of help as well to you.